# Cannot save a model when a regularizer is added to a model from tf.keras.applications

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

I use python 3.7 with Tensorflow 2.2.0. I would like to train a MobileNet-V2 from scratch, therefore I take the already built model and add a regularizer to all required layers. The model compiles well and I am able to fit it. However, when saving the model, I encounter the following error:

```
  File "/mnt/disk1/anaconda3/envs/py37/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/saved_model/nested_structure_coder.py", line 82, in _map_structure
    "No encoder for object [%s] of type [%s]." % (str(pyobj), type(pyobj)))
tensorflow.python.saved_model.nested_structure_coder.NotEncodableError: No encoder for object [<tensorflow.python.keras.layers.convolutional.Conv2D object at 0x7fd2f00469d0>] of type [<class 'tensorflow.python.keras.layers.convolutional.Conv2D'>].
```

Without the regularization added (config.regularizer.name = "" in the code below), the model can be fitted and saved successfully. I wonder is this is a bug or am I doing something wrong here?

```
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow.keras.applications import MobileNetV2

model = MobileNetV2(input_shape=ds_info["shape"], classes=ds_info["n_classes"], weights=None, include_top=True)

if config.regularizer.name == "l2":
    l2_reg = config.regularizer.weight
    for layer in model.layers:
        if isinstance(layer, tf.keras.layers.DepthwiseConv2D):
            layer.add_loss(lambda la=layer: tf.keras.regularizers.l2(l2_reg)(la.depthwise_kernel))
        elif isinstance(layer, tf.keras.layers.Conv2D) or isinstance(layer, tf.keras.layers.Dense):
            layer.add_loss(lambda la=layer: tf.keras.regularizers.l2(l2_reg)(la.kernel))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out, the lambda function should not take any parameters, according to the documentation. However, when I was not passing the parameters, it resulted in another very strange error (it was about the `Dense` layer not having the `depthwise_kernel`, which is obvious and should not have happened, but somehow it happened). Digging deeper, I found this is a bug which is well explained in [here](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/38891).

So, my final solution was to define two separate functions for regularization as is suggested in the link above.

```
def add_l2_regularization_kernel(layer, weight):
    def _add_l2_regularization_kernel():
        l2 = tf.keras.regularizers.l2(weight)
        return l2(layer.kernel)
    return _add_l2_regularization_kernel


def add_l2_regularization_depthwise_kernel(layer, weight):
    def _add_l2_regularization_depthwise_kernel():
        l2 = tf.keras.regularizers.l2(weight)
        return l2(layer.depthwise_kernel)
    return _add_l2_regularization_depthwise_kernel


if config.has("regularizer"):
    if config.regularizer.name == "l2":
        l2_reg = config.regularizer.weight
        for layer in model.layers:
            if isinstance(layer, tf.keras.layers.DepthwiseConv2D):
                layer.add_loss(add_l2_regularization_depthwise_kernel(layer, l2_reg))
            elif isinstance(layer, tf.keras.layers.Conv2D) or isinstance(layer, tf.keras.layers.Dense):
                layer.add_loss(add_l2_regularization_kernel(layer, l2_reg))
```

Comment: When in the "work around" weeds, it would be most helpful to provide a more complete example that ties it all together including, for example, a for loop through the layers to add the regularizer as well as the tontextualized use of the "config.has" conditional.